# Strange copy and paste issue across 3 Windows 7 Pro machines

Tags: windows-7, copy-paste

I have 6 users seated on a pod of desks all going through a basic Netgear gigabit switch which then links into our main Netgear 48 port switch up in the server room. In the past week or so 3 of these users (all sat in the same side of the pod) have experienced a problem where if one of them copies some text, the other 2 users paste, whatever was copied from user A will be pasted onto user B + C's machines.

We've tested this across all 3 users machines and it doesn't matter which one copies; the others can paste it. The issue doesn't occur when copying pictures, video or music, etc. No software to add this functionality into Win7 has been installed so I'm wondering if anyone has come across a similar situation before.

Comment: Restore the default image to these machines to verify software was not installed, because this behavior, is not a feature of Windows itself. Access to the clipboard is a protected mechanic in Windows and requires user permission when done through software ( unlesss the permision was already granted ).

Comment: Have you used imaging software to install these machines? Are they exact copies?

Comment: No imaging software was used they were all individual installs and these machines have been working without issue for months.

Comment: @Dave - There has to be third-party software installed.  Try switching the ports on these 3 devices with the other 3 devices.  See if you can replicate the issue against the following configuration where side X is the problem child and Side Y is the golden boy ( in other words the side without the prblem ) x y x y x y

Comment: wha tar ethe users doing? Are they all logging into an RDP server or alike?   Does it happen across all programs?  Does is happen on the suspect computers for other users?  How about for the suspect users on other computers?

Comment: @Ramhound I've checked for any installed software which would cause such a thing to happen and I can't see any on any of the machines. I've got them testing swapping the ports over on the switch to see if the problem moves to the users on the other side of the pod.

Comment: @techie007 No RDP servers involved they are just using their domain accounts to log into their machines and no roaming profiles are being used. We are not even using document redirection or anything similar. It happens across all programs but only with text. Tested it using IE10, Firefox latest, Chrome, Google Docs, Word and Spark instant chat program.

Comment: It's a software issue almost guaranteed.  I have trouble believing your switch ports confuse clipboard data, but nothing else. ;) Don't look for installed software, look for running processes.  For example, "[Ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/)" can do similar to what you are describing, and has a portable version (which wouldn't be _installed_, just there).

Comment: OK we swapped over a few of the network ports just to make sure and it didn't make a difference. I logged onto one of the machines with my account and that took that machine out of the equation leaving the other 2 still able to copy and paste between them. After the original user logged back in they were no longer part of the copy and paste group. So I've had all 3 users log out and then back into their own accounts and that seems to have solved it for now. Their machines are rebooted a few times a week so I suppose it's a wait and see situation for now. Thank you all for the help.

Comment: I want that feature... (just kidding). I hope you find out what process caused this. Clipboard text should never be able to travel over the network... on its own.

Comment: If the problem returns, try to disconnect clients one by one to pinpoint the machine that is "hosting" that feature :D

Comment: It appears to be a problem with Tight VNC which we have installed on the clients. The users use Tight VNC to connect to another machine which displays call stats. When the users are connected at the same time through VNC the copy and paste problem arises. I'm still a little baffled by the whole situation as it still means that some how the clients are sharing a clipboard.

Comment: @Dave This is not so strange. TightVNC shares the clipboard with the machine it's connected to. If all machines are connected to the same machine this problem can arise. You can disable clipboard sharing. Try this first on the machine all other machines connect to (in the setting in systray). If that does not work disable it on the other machines in the setting (top-left of the window).

Comment: @Rik Thanks Rik I'll give that a try. I checked on the VNC server and there's no option for it but on the client machine I checked the "Disable clipboard transfer" option in the restrictions section of the connection options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that in this case TightVNC was the reason the clipboard-data is transported over the network to other users.

The 3 users who had the problem of a shared clipboard over the network all had a session with TightVNC open to another machine which displays call stats.

TightVNC shares the clipboard with the machine it's connected to. So each clipboard action of the user is send to the connected machine, who in its turn sends it back to the other connected users.

To prevent clipboard sharing with TightVNC you can disable clipboard sharing. On the client/user machines check the `Disable clipboard transfer` option in the "Connection options"-dialog.

[image: Connection options]